# Duvida sobre subquery

Tags: php, mysql

Eu possuo várias imagens para um site que estou fazendo. Queria que mostrar apenas a última imagem que foi cadastrada para determinado produto.
Eu sei que com *left join* vai puxar todas as imagens e que preciso de uma *subquery* pra poder puxar essa última imagem, porém essa *query* não está funcionando.

Obrigado desde já

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$this->prefix}produtos p ";
$query .= " left join {$this->prefix}imagens img on img.img_pro_id = pro_id ";
$query .= " INNER JOIN {$this->prefix}categorias c ON p.pro_categoria = c.cate_id ";
$query .= " WHERE pro_ativo = 1 ORDER BY pro_id DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou utilizar OUTER APPLY ao invés de LEFT JOIN?

Por exemplo, se você tiver uma tabela com as imagens por ID do produto em que você possua algum tipo de índice para ordenar pelo mais recente (por exemplo, data da imagem), você pode usar uma query parecida com esta abaixo para selecionar o item mais novo.

```
SELECT *
FROM {$this->prefix}produtos P
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1
    [CAMINHO_IMAGEM]
    FROM {$this->prefix}imagens AX
    WHERE AX.pro_id = P.pro_id
    ORDER BY [ALGUM_INDICE] DESC
) IMG
```

Comment: Não resolveu pra mim amigo... acabei conseguindo montar a subquery no outro dia

Comment: @gabrielfalieri você pode responder a sua própria pergunta para ajudar outras pessoas que por acaso cheguem aqui